Testing NodeJS code with jest that overrides process.env.TZ multiple times
I am trying to test code with jest that needs to override process.env.TZ multiple times during the test. I am using an external lib (later.js) to expand crontab entries that can be defined for different time zones using CRON_TZ overrides.
It looks like jest has an internal version of process.env for the test. This internal version is updated during the test, but any Date objects that are created use the system default time zone. The following code demonstrates that:
const process = require('process');

function tzDate(timeZone)
{
  const save = process.env.TZ;
  process.env.TZ = timeZone;
  const d = new Date();
  const offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
  process.env.TZ = save;

  return offset;
}

const offsets = [
  tzDate('Europe/Amsterdam'),
  tzDate('Europe/Bucharest')
];

console.log(offsets);

if (typeof expect === 'function')
{
  expect(offsets).toEqual([ -120, -180 ]);
}


Running without jest produces (in my time zone):
$ node tz.test.js
[ -120, -180 ]

While running this under jest produces:
 jest  tz.test.js
  console.log
    [ -120, -120 ]

      at Object.log (tz.test.js:19:9)

 FAIL  ./tz.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

      Array [
        -120,
    -   -180,
    +   -120,
      ]

Clearly, jest is somehow providing the default time zone to Date.
Is there any way to make this work?
